# How do I use http2 with Node on Heroku (using Koa)

Tags: node.js, heroku, http2

I have the following code...

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = new Koa();
...
app.listen(PORT)
```

This works great both locally and in Heroku. So now I want to use Http2 so I change to the following...

```
const server = http2.createSecureServer(
    {
        "key": fs.readFileSync('./server-key.pem'),
        "cert": fs.readFileSync('./server-cert.pem')
    }, 
    app.callback()
)
server.listen(PORT);
```

This works ok locally, however, when I upload to Heroku I get...

```
2021-06-24T00:43:00.383108+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=my-app.herokuapp.com request_id=604f4a2c-8dd2-4cfa-9cf2-3cce5ef76070 fwd="..." dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

So how do I get http2 working with Node, Koa, and Heroku?

Comment: It appears from [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#http-versions-supported) that Heroku does not yet support http/2.

Answer (score 5):

Per [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#not-supported) on devcenter.heroku.com, Heroku does not yet support http/2.

Comment: I'll upvote for now but no check cause doesnt really solve it.

Comment: @Jackie - Well, we answered your question.  Heroku doesn't support http/2 yet.  So, maybe it isn't the answer you wanted, but it is the answer to your question.  Heroku does not support http/2 and there is nothing you can do about that other than picking a different hosting provider that does.

Comment: @Jackie this has always been the case on Heroku and it's unlikely they will ever support HTTP/2 - best to pick a better hosting provider. Check https://render.com - it supports HTTP/2 out of the box.

Comment: @TheoLampert Why is it unlikely for them to ever support HTTP/2?

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert People have been asking for a very long time and they've never responded. Since the Salesforce acquisition several years ago they no longer innovate or release any new features.

Comment: @TheoLampert What do people tend to switch to as an alternative to Heroku?

Comment: We use Heroku for our production site still but are now using render.com for our PR apps and may switch to them in the near future.  It's much like Heroku but offers a little more flexibility.  

DO NOT USE QOVERY!  We used them for PR apps just to run a few PR builds & it needed a minimum of 5 medium AWS instances.  They kept building it up as 3-5 large or 2xl and it ended up costing me $2k/mo in AWS fees.  Luckily we moved away from that but still feeling the burn.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an add-on like https://elements.heroku.com/addons/expeditedwaf or you can use cloudflare. If you decide to use cloudflare, make sure you add a SSL certificate between cloudflare and heroku.

Comment: This is answer should be the one because indeed Heroku does not provide HTTP/2 out of the box but you can use the expedited WAF add-on.

Comment: Support for HTTP/2 with this add-on starts at $250 per month.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively have a look at [expeditedcdn](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/expeditedcdn).
It should be way cheaper than the full blown Web App Firewall.